# Sanity problems uploading image from browser

Tags: sveltekit, sanity

## SOLVED

```
export async function createImageAsset(image: File | Blob): Promise<SanityDocument> {
  const stream = Buffer.from(await image.arrayBuffer());
  return await client.assets.upload('image', stream, {
    filename: image.name,
    contentType: image.type
  });
}
```

---

For context I'm trying to do this in sveltekit, in a +page.server.ts file, so I'm not sure if I'm stumbling on something to do with sveltekit?

I've read the documentation at https://www.sanity.io/docs/assets and verified with https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client#examples-uploading-assets-from-the-browser that I can upload files and blobs from the browser.

This is a helper function that I have;

```
export async function createImageAsset(image: File | Blob): Promise<SanityImageAssetDocument> {
  console.log('createImageAsset', image);
  console.log('createImageAsset', image.name);
  console.log('createImageAsset', image.type);
  return await client.assets.upload('image', image, {
    filename: image.name,
    contentType: image.type
  });
}
```

although, I received the below output and error message;

```bash
createImageAsset Blob { size: 30166, type: 'image/avif' }
createImageAsset 1.avif
createImageAsset image/avif
Error: Request body must be a string, buffer or stream, got object
```

To me it does indeed look like a blob, and should thus be able to upload?

---

Edit; not solved, but there must be something weird going on when the basic example on sanity docs

```
// Create a file with "foo" as its content
const file = new File(['foo'], 'foo.txt', {type: 'text/plain'})
// Upload it
client.assets
  .upload('file', file)
  .then((document) => {
    console.log('The file was uploaded!', document)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Upload failed:', error.message)
  })
```

Also gives the following error

```
Upload failed: Request body must be a string, buffer or stream, got object
```